# boolean &= assignment operator meaning

Tags: java, boolean, bit-manipulation, variable-assignment

if I have two variables

```
boolean k = true;
boolean m = false;
```

what does the following do;

```
k &= m;
```

Comment: Why don't you run those three lines and see what `k` and `m` both equal afterwards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the compound assignment operator, which is equivalent to:

```
k = (boolean)(k & m);
```

Comment: yes I understand but what does the value of k equal?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad What does `&` operator do?

Comment: It performs bit-wise and operation of the operators

Comment: its a check, if X == x & Y == y type of thing

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: Well what did the value of `k` equal before? It's very unclear which bit you're still confused by.

Comment: k is set to true at the top, but I think I understand now

Comment: That's a logical and., this is a bit-wise operator

Comment: @darknight These are booleans.  It doesn't make too much sense to talk about "bitwise" operations on booleans.

Comment: @darknight No, really it's not.

Comment: @darknight: It's a logical operator in this context.

Comment: The difference between `&&=` and `&=` for booleans is simply that in the `&&=` case, the right side won't be evaluated if the left side is false.

Comment: Isn't that the bit-wise operator and not the logical operator?

Comment: @darknight Think about what you're saying.  What would bitwise mean for booleans?  The word makes no sense in this context.

Comment: My bad, i thought size of boolean operators are 1-bit

Comment: @darknight: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.

Comment: @DavidWallace: There is no `&&=`... (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.12)

Comment: @rohit, +1 for type-casting to boolean!

Comment: thanks for the help guys, the reason I was confused is I'm working on updating some code for work, and it looks like there's some unnecessary stuff, so i was trying to understand why its there

Comment: @OliCharlesworth  Oops.  Red face over here!  Kind of silly though; it ought to exist, because it would behave differently from `&=`.